# What is the appropiate Non-parametric test for study with 3 conditions?

Tags: paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank, kruskal-wallis-test

The IV has 3 separate conditions & the DV measures Pre & post scores (ultimately to see what condition has the biggest effect on the scores - if there is any). The data is non-parametric- would it be better to use Wilcoxon or Kruskal-Wallis? Many thanks.

Comment: Data are neither parametric nor nonparametric. What do you mean to say about the data?

Answer (score 2):

The options you suggest in the tags are mutually incompatible as the Wilcoxon signed ranks is for paired data but Kruskal  Wallis for independent. If your three groups are independent you can form a difference score for each person and use K-W on them. If you want to just compare two groups you can use the Wilcoxon Mann Whitney test which is the two sample analogue of K-W.